# Update cart library in Codeigniter v2.2

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to update my shopping cart (change quantity of the selling products by client) and I'm using the cart library. when I submit the update button, the page will redirect as I want but it won't update and shows the previous value and I don't get any error. what is wrong with my codes???

my controller code for update is

```
public function update($in_cart = null){
        $data= $_POST;      
        $this->cart->update($data);        

        //show cart page
        redirect ('cart','refresh');      
    }
```

and my view code is

```
<form action="cart/update" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style= "width: 100%" border="0" >
            <tr>
                <th>QTY</th>
                <th>item description</th>
                <th style="text-align: right">Item Price</th>
            </tr>
            <?php $i=1;  ?> <!-- $i=1 is a counter -->
            <?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) : ?> 
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $i.'[rowid]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $items['rowid'];?> "/>
            <tr>
                <td id="cart-qty"><input type="text"  name="<?php echo $i.'[qty]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $items['qty'];?>" maxlength="3" size="5"> </td>
                <td><?php echo $items ['name'];?></td>
                <td style="text-align: right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['price']);?> </td>
            </tr>
                    <?php $i++ ;  ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td class="right" style="text-align: right">$<?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total());?></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br>
        <p><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update Cart</button>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="cart">go to cart</a></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your Controller function to:

```
public function update(){
  $rowid=$this->input->post('rowid');
  $cart=$this->cart->contents();
  foreach ($cart as $cart) {
  //now match your item whose qty is updated
  if($rowid==$cart['rowid']){
   $qty=$cart['qty'];
   }
  }
  $data=array(
  'rowid'=>$rowid,
  'qty'=>$qty+1
  );
  $data=$this->cart->update($data);
  redirect ('cart','refresh');      
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code but it did not work. I got two error with your code

Comment: still got an error with them, I guess my own controller should be right because I don't have any error with it and probably the problem is from my view.

Answer (score 0):

in update generally we are using id for update any row in this case we need also a id so in cart library at the added it`s create a automatic row_id of every product so you have to use row_id to update cart content please follow below image --

[image]

Comment: I saw my codes from an Udemy tutorials video and I've written them exactly according to the video, in the video the instructor says when we use  {$data= $_POST;} we're taking all the post data and put them into $data.

Comment: I don't know how to write in another way. what would be the post value of qty and row_id ? can you write it for my view please?

Comment: like that -- foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) {
   $data = array( 
        'rowid'  => $items['rowid'],
               'id'      => $id,
               'price'   => $product1[0]->selling_price*$price1,
               'name'    => $product1[0]->product_name,
               'options' => array('image' =>$product1[0]->image1, 'unit' => $product1[0]->unit, 'quantity' => $quantity)
            );
    $this->cart->update($data);
  }